# SQLite synchronization when accessed by applications on different machines

Tags: sqlite, synchronization, locking

I'm wondering how SQLite implements it. Is it based on file-locking? Surely the entire DB isn't locked for every user that accesses it; that would be extremely inefficient. Is it based on multiple files or just one big file?

Would be nice if someone could give a short overview of how synchronization and locking is done in sqlite, or, of course, provide a link to one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [the SQL Lite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5) and [this on locking.](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html) Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it does. Had no idea only one writer is supported in sqlite.