# Sqlite data insert from multiple applications

Tags: sqlite

I have a Sqlite database with two tables.  One table contains parameters to do calculations with.  The other table contains the results of the calculations.  Obviously the calculations should only be done once, that is why each table has a column with the same name so that the parameters and results can be recognized as a pair.

I have an application that retrieves the parameters, do the calculations and update the database with the results.  Using one instance of this application works great.  The trouble begins when running multiple instances.

Two problems persist:

1. The instances calculate the same parameters since the parameters to pull from the database is determined by the completed test results in the database.  This problem I can maybe deal with by making use of csv files which all instances have access to to determine which parameter set is being calculated but a better solution will be appreciated.
2. The database is updated at the same time by the different instances.  This does not work with Sqlite and the application skips the results and goes on to the next without updating the database or throws errors.

Are there maybe built-in functions in Sqlite to overcome these problems?

If anything is not clear please let me know and I will try to explain in more detail.

Comment: Sounds like you want to synchronize access to the database, in which case [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589675/sqlite-synchronization-when-accessed-by-applications-on-different-machines) discussion might help you.

Comment: Yes I see, thinking if implementing a "broker" that handles the transactions to the database and receiving the data from the clients